# Retaining route details on MVC Form Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a basic MVC form which is accessed through a **GET** Action with 3 string parameters pulled from the route.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Application(string x, string y, string z)
{
    //create model, setup form, etc...

    return View(model);
}
```

The route to access this form is configured as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute("Application", 
    "application/{x}/{y}/{z}",
    new
    {
        controller = "Application",
        action = "Application",
        x = "",
        y = "",
        z = ""
    });
```

And the form is configured as follows:

```
Html.BeginForm("Application", "Application", FormMethod.Post)
```

All of this works until I click submit on the resulting form. From a routing perspective the correct POST Action is called and the Model is bound correctly. The problem is I have lost all the **x/y/z** route information which I still need. **How can I preserve the route information?**

I've tried a couple things:

- Added route details to the Form in Hidden fields which are added to the form content correctly but never get returned in the Model on postback
- Tried using the **RouteValueDictionary** overload for **Html.BeginForm** but can't figure out how to make it work. I may just need a proper example of how to use it and how to access the state from the Controller

### Update: This adds **View** sample to help address comments made regarding the use of Hidden Fields

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Application", "Application", FormMethod.Post, new
                                                                        {
                                                                            autocomplete = "on", 
                                                                            id = "LoanApplication", 
                                                                            novalidate = string.Empty, 
                                                                            name = "Application"
                                                                        }))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.x)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.y)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.z)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DigiCertId)
        <br />
        <input id="SubmitButton" type="submit" value="@Resources.SubmitApplicationButton" title="@Resources.SubmitApplicationButtonDescription" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

Comment: What does your POST method look like?

Comment: @vcsjones Sorry... it currently looks like `[HttpPost] public ActionResult Application(Application application)`. I tried a version that had the same signature as the 'HttpGet' method plus the `Application` argument, but that did not seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really put these properties in the model, then have a `HiddenFor` for each one, like so:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.x)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.y)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.z)
```

Then in your post method (assuming it's like this), you can pass them in the `RouteValueDictionary` to the `Get` Method, like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Application(MyModel model) //whatever type your model is
{
    //do whatever your post method does before redirect
    return RedirectToAction("Application", new { x = model.x, y = model.y, z = model.z});
}
```

Comment: I did add them to the model (and added HiddenFor), but Hidden fields don't seem to get POST'd back for all browsers. This led to things working in some browsers but not others.

Comment: That should definitely work in all browsers. Which were you having trouble with?

Comment: When adding the HiddenFor it renders correctly `<input id="x" name="x" type="text" value="foo" />`. But when I click submit and look at the content via Fiddler the values for hidden fields are missing `x=&y=&z=&DigiCertId=abc123`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention it was using IE 9

Comment: @JoeGeeky hmm now that's very strange. Can you post your *exact* view code?

Comment: I've added a stripped down version of the **View** above.

Comment: Looking at your view, nothing seems out of the ordinary. I've used your **exact** code in a sample project and it works perfectly fine, Chrome and IE9. It suggests that your problem lies elsewhere, outside of the code you have posted? There's not multiple fields with the same `name` as the items you are trying to bind is there?

Answer (score 0):

in addition to the ans suggested by mattytommo. i would recommend using `TempData` collection in asp.net MVC. this saves the data using the session storage but does it temprorarily and the data gets deleted once you access it.
this is present specifically for these purposes
so you can save the data in TempData as `TempData["Values"] = new {X=x,Y=y,Z=z};`
then access the `TempData["Values"]` after the post

Comment: Thats an option but would require out-of-process state management or stick-sessions. I'm still hoping for something that allows me to keep things relatively stateless.

Comment: out of process state managnment YES. sticky sessions NO. are your not using Sessions in your site?

Comment: At the moment we don't need sessions. With any luck this won't require a state server either.